# Can't get the length of a dict after adding element dynamically in jQuery

Tags: jquery, dictionary, key-value

Firstly, I am using ajax to accept JSON data by adding to a dict variable, which I declared before ajax.

I want to get the length of the dict, but here the output:

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVRXK.png)

and the message next to the dict output shows "Value below was evaluated just now":

[the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUQl9.png)

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var table_id = $('#table_id').text();
        var list_length = $.words_list(table_id);
    });

    //function
    jQuery.extend({
        'words_list': function (id) {
            var send_list = {};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/get_wordslist/' + id,
                success: function (returnData) {
                    $.each(returnData, function (item, value) {
                        send_list[item] = value;
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log(send_list);
            console.log('length:' + Object.keys(send_list).length);
            return 1;//just for returning
        }
    });
</script>
```

Basing on the message, I thought I need to use another variable to record length, like this:

```
<script>    
$(function () {
        var table_id = $('#table_id').text();
        var list_length = $.words_list(table_id);
    });

    jQuery.extend({
        'words_list': function (id) {
            var send_list = {};
            var list_length = 0;// add a variable

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/get_wordslist/' + id,
                success: function (returnData) {
                    $.each(returnData, function (item, value) {
                        send_list[item] = value;
                        list_length++;//record increase
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log(send_list);
            console.log('length:' + list_length);//show
            return 1;//just for returning
        }
    });
</script>
```

But the output was the same. And I compare with a simple code like this:

```
var dict = {
    "Jeremy": 20,
    "Jimmy": 30
};
console.log(dict);
console.log(Object.keys(dict).length);
```

Here is the output:

[example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX8yx.png)

This is my expected result. According to the message, I think adding elements to dict dynamically is the reason of the problem. But I tried to use a variable to record length, failed too. Now I have no idea to solve the problem. Please help me and tell me why, thank you first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ajax is asynchronous so at the time you `console.log('length:' + list_length);`, the success function hasn't run yet. To get your expected result, you need to log in the success function. Something like this:

```
var send_list = {};
var list_length = 0;// add a variable

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/get_wordslist/' + id,
   success: function (returnData) {
      $.each(returnData, function (item, value) {
         send_list[item] = value;
         list_length++;//record increase
      });
      // Log here
      console.log(send_list);
      console.log('length:' + list_length);
   }
});
```